# Format SQL query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to set the width on the returned column result from a SQL query.

I run a query like Select Product from ConfigScheduling where Product is an Nvarchar(Max) column.
The result in SQL Server Management Studio with Results to Grid is a 90 char wide visible column, with the full result present, but not visible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, SQL Server Management Studio cannot pull the whole nvarchar(max) field into display and won't attempt to either.  The only way to fully access the resultset is to use a third party tool or display it in a gridview or something in a webapp.

Comment: Results to text file gives the entire results.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find it by default, but if you double-click on the right part of the Column Header it will stretch like in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Tools>Options>Query Results>SQL Server>Results to Grid>Non XML data
Tools>Options>Query Results>SQL Server>Results to Text>Maximum number of characters displayed in each column.

If these still don't suit your needs, you'll need to use another tool such as bcp or sqlcmd/osql.